# Sharepoint Modified By and Created By are Blank

Tags: 2007, wss

When any user other than a site collection administrator goes onto a document library or a survey for example they can't see any details in the modified by or the created by columns.

I've given the user full control and they still can't see anything in the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Mat, I am a Sharepoint (intermediate lvl) admin. I make tutorials all the time for Sharepoint. What I have read is that you are having trouble with permissions. What I would suggest doing is trying to look into inherited permissions of certain library's and folders within to see if they are inherited. Plus, I have found out that there are 2 levels of permissions within Sharepoint, one is at folder level and the other is at library level. When you change these, be sure that when you change one, the other doesn't change. This could be what is causing your problems. It takes time to find out these things on Sharepoint depending on your environment, so I would try testing on a few people at a time to investigate certian possibilites on what could gain them access to the libraries details. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mat - unfortunately they have full control for both library and folder so it's not that.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?